# get posts from Rest Api by meta_key/meta_value not working

Tags: rest-api, query-posts

I have a function that fetches all the latest posts which works fine. But i wish to fetch only the posts that have a specific value from a custom option.

[image]

But adding the meta_key/meta_value does not change anything, i still get the latest blog posts regardless of those values added.

```
getLatestPosts (count = 4){
        return this.get("posts", {
            context: "embed",
            per_page: count.toString(10),
            _embed: "",
            meta_key: "_bunyad_featured_post",
            meta_value: "1"
        });
    }
```

Am i using the wrong query options for this? Or do i need to add something for that custom post option to be usable through the Rest Api?

Comment: have you registered your post meta on the PHP side? Or is it raw unregistered post meta? Where does the `.get` method come from? Note that querying for posts via their post meta values is more expensive/slower, it would be faster/more efficient to have used a custom taxonomy for grouping posts into featured and non-featured, be that via a dedicated "featured" custom taxonomy, or via a more general utility taxonomy, this could in the best case scenario be as much as 1000x faster

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for the `posts` endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts) does not indicate that `meta_key` or `meta_value` are accepted parameters.

You will likely have most success by [defining your own endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) to accept those parameters.

This question may be helpful:
[REST API and filtering by meta value](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/346689/rest-api-and-filtering-by-meta-value)